# How do I show the first two posts only?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am quit new to WordPress theme development. I am trying to show only the first two recent posts on my homepage but whatever I do the code always loops through the whole posts. Any help is appreciated.

**index.php:**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php $args = array(
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'offset' => 0,
    'category' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'draft, publish, future, pending, private',
    'suppress_filters' => true );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : 
        if(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('banner-image') ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('banner-image') ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="pull-right marTop20">
                                <h4>Most recent posts</h4>
                                <?php $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args); ?>
                                <?php foreach($recent_posts as $recent){ ?>
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <?php echo '<li class="list-item"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> '; ?>
                                </ul>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php 
            endif;
            endif;
        ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set 2 to `'numberposts'` parameter?

Comment: @bhelmet That's for the sidebar, it get's the first 10 post titles. What I want now is to show the first two posts as well

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$args = array ( 
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'post_status' => 'draft, publish, future, pending, private',
          'posts_per_page' => 2,
          'orderby' => 'post_date',
        );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    /* Your Code */
  endwhile; 
endif ;
```

Comment: This works but now I have a new problem. I am using bootstrap as my framework and I showing them with a grid. The posts are showing as block and not inline.

Comment: I think that was some css issue or some class change in bootstrap so you have to check in your HTML other wise data will come as you want in question

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over the *wp_get_recent_posts* return value:

```
foreach($recent_posts as $recent_post)  {
  // stuff
}
```

Also, set in **args** the `numberpost` to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Change Line 3 to:

```
'numberposts' => 2,
```

Here is the full documentation for the function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts